# Could not convert from <brace-enclosed initializer list> to std::map

Tags: c++, arrays, pointers, function-pointers, stdmap

I am stuck on a problem and I know that some similar questions have already been posted here, but I have not been able to solve the problem yet based on their answers. Could someone please help me with this?

I have the following class in a .h file:

```
class A 
{
private:
    
    struct ARGS
    {
        size_t length{0};
        std::string str{""};
    };
    
    typedef int(A::*FUNCPTR)(const std::vector<ARGS> &); 
    std::map<const std::string, FUNCPTR> func_map
    {    
        {"PRINT_HW",
          [this](const std::vector<ARGS> args){
            validate(args, 0);
            A::cmd_phw();
          }
        },
        {"PRINT_NAME",
          [this](const std::vector<ARGS> args){
            validate(args, 1);
            A::cmd_pn(args[0]);
          }
        },
        {"PRINT_NAME_SURNAME",
          [this](const std::vector<ARGS> args){
            validate(args, 2);
            A::cmd_pns(args[0], args[1]);
          }
        },
    };

    // function declaration for the existing commands. 
    int cmd_phw();
    int cmd_pn(ARGS args1);
    int cmd_pns(ARGS args1, ARGS args2);
 
    static void validate(const std::vector<ARGS> &args, size_t needed)
    {
        if (args.size() != needed)
        {
            throw std::invalid_argument("Wrong number of arguments!");
        }
    }    

public:
    A(); // Class constructor declaration
    int call_print(const std::string& str, const std::vector<ARGS> &args);
};
```

And in the .cpp file I have all the definitions, including the `call_print` as follows:

```
int A::call_print(const std::string& str, const std::vector<ARGS> &args)
{
  FUNCPTR fp = func_map[str];
  int r = (this->*fp)(args);

  return r;
}
```

But unfortunatelly it results in an error:

```
could not convert ‘{{"PRINT_HW", <lambda closure object>A::<lambda(std::vector<A::ARGS>)>{((A*)this)}}, {"PRINT_NAME", <lambda closure object>A::<lambda(std::vector<A::ARGS>)>{((A*)this)}}, {"PRINT_NAME_SURNAME", <lambda closure object>A::<lambda(std::vector<A::ARGS>)>{((A*)this)}}}’ from ‘<brace-enclosed initializer list>’ to ‘std::map<const std::__cxx11::basic_string<char>, int (A::*)(const std::vector<A::ARGS>&)>’
```

Comment: Lambda is not a pointer to member function and cannot be converted into one.

Comment: Suggest that you use `std::function<void(const std::vector<ARGS>&)>` as the target for your map instead.

Answer (score 1):

You can't convert a lambda into a pointer-to-member-function.  A lambda can be converted into a plain pointer-to-function, but only if it is *non-capturing*.

Since you want to use *capturing* lambdas, you will have to use `std::function` instead as your `std::map` value type, eg:

```
class A 
{
public:
    struct ARG
    {
        size_t length{0};
        std::string str{""};
    };

    using ARGS = std::vector<ARG>;

private:    
    using FUNCPTR = std::function<int(const ARGS&)>;
    std::map<std::string, FUNCPTR> func_map
    {    
        {"PRINT_HW",
          [this](const ARGS& args) -> int {
            A::validate(args, 0);
            return cmd_phw();
          }
        },
        {"PRINT_NAME",
          [this](const ARGS& args) -> int {
            A::validate(args, 1);
            return cmd_pn(args[0]);
          }
        },
        {"PRINT_NAME_SURNAME",
          [this](const ARGS& args) -> int {
            A::validate(args, 2);
            return cmd_pns(args[0], args[1]);
          }
        },
    };

    // function declaration for the existing commands. 
    int cmd_phw();
    int cmd_pn(const ARG& args1);
    int cmd_pns(const ARG& args1, const ARG& args2);
 
    static void validate(const ARGS &args, size_t needed)
    {
        if (args.size() != needed)
        {
            throw std::invalid_argument("Wrong number of arguments!");
        }
    }    

public:
    A(); // Class constructor declaration
    int call_print(const std::string& str, const ARGS &args);
};
```

```
int A::call_print(const std::string& str, const ARGS &args)
{
  return func_map.at(str)(args);
}
```

Answer (score -2):

The error message suggests that the type of the initializer list passed to the `std::map` constructor is incompatible with the type of the map's `value_type`. Specifically, the map's `value_type` is `int (A::*)(const std::vector<ARGS>&)`, which is a pointer to member function type, while the initializer list provides lambda functions that have a different type.

To fix the error, you need to make sure that the lambda functions have the same type as the pointer to member functions. One way to do this is to define the lambda functions with the same signature as the member functions, like this:

```
{
    {"PRINT_HW", &A::cmd_phw},
    {"PRINT_NAME", &A::cmd_pn},
    {"PRINT_NAME_SURNAME", &A::cmd_pns}
}
```

Alternatively, you can define a type alias for the lambda functions with the correct signature and use it in the map declaration, like this:

```
using FUNCPTR = int(A::*)(const std::vector<ARGS>&);
using LambdaType = std::function<int(A*, const std::vector<ARGS>&)>;
std::map<std::string, FUNCPTR> func_map {
    {"PRINT_HW", static_cast<FUNCPTR>(&A::cmd_phw)},
    {"PRINT_NAME", static_cast<FUNCPTR>(&A::cmd_pn)},
    {"PRINT_NAME_SURNAME", static_cast<FUNCPTR>(&A::cmd_pns)}
};
```

Define a type alias `LambdaType` for the lambda functions with the correct signature, and then use `static_cast` to convert the lambdas to the pointer-to-member-function type `FUNCPTR`. Note that we also need to pass a pointer to the object (`this`) as the first argument to the member functions when calling them through the pointer.

Comment: `cmd_phw`, `cmd_pn`, and `cmd_pns` are not lambdas. A lambda cannot be converted into a pointer-to-member-function, only to a pointer-to-function (and only if the lambda is non-capturing). This feels like a ChatGPT-generated answer, especially since it suggests defining `LambdaType` but doesn't use it, and also the `static_cast`s won't work since you need `reinterpret_cast` to cast a pointer-to-member-function to a different type.